# Ask Question - Tags box: Placeholder

Tags: discussion, tagging

I'm not sure how much of an impact this has on choosing tags, but this seems a bit contradicting at the very least:

The Tags box has the following placeholder:

> at least one tag such as (**bugs** image-processing plotting), max 5 tags

Image: [image: Tag box]

And the description of the [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) tag:

> This tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted
>   by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug.
>   **Please do not use this tag for new questions.** Please use the standard
>   bugs header instead of version tags in conjunction with this tag.

(emphasis mine)

If possible, it might therefore be a good idea to change the list to different example tags

Comment: [That's not what I see.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S5TA6.png)

Comment: Very strange - for me it's the same as in your image now..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't worry it should not happen often as it seems they are picked randomly each couple of hours:

[What determines the example tags? (tags in the placeholder of the tags section when asking new question)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279519/233085)

Don't have much experience with other sites but [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) usage seems to be unique here, for this community benefit, so we probably should not hope it will be filtered out for us.

But again, it isn't a major issue as it is not a fixed set of example tags.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I was quite confused after @Szabolcs' comment ;)